# Python regular expression not returning desired results

Tags: python, regex

I have a string like this

```
{test}{test2}{test3}
```

i have a function with regex that is supposed to extract everything between the {}

```
def cleanup():
    mystring = str('{test}{test2}{test3}')
    rx = re.findall(r'{(.*)}', mystring)
    for row in rx:
        return(rx)
```

but when I print this function instead of getting the desired

```
test, test2, test3
```

it return

```
test}{test2}{test3
```

any ideas?

Comment: try this `r'{(.*?)}`

Comment: Style tip: `mystring = str('{test}{test2}{test3}')` can be more concisely written as `mystring = '{test}{test2}{test3}'`. Python is a dynamic language so you don't have to explicitly tell a variable that it is a string; it can deduce that by itself.

Answer (score 3):

Use `.*?` for [non-greedy](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#greedy-versus-non-greedy) evaluation, i.e. for finding more shorter matches instead of one long one.

```
>>> re.findall(r'{(.*?)}', mystring)
['test', 'test2', 'test3']
```

---

BTW, in your function, when you do

```
for row in rx:
    return(rx)
```

this will just return the first `row` and ignore the rest! Instead, you could either just return the list, without a loop, i.e.

```
return rx
```

or you could turn the function into a generator, and `yield` the several results

```
for row in rx:
    yield rx
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
(?<={)([^}]+)
```

[Regex live here.](https://regex101.com/r/iZ9oG9/2)

Explaining:

```
(?<={)          # starting with '{'
(               # start of capturing group
    [^}]+       # any non '}' character
)               # end of capturing group
```

For your input, it does 34 steps.

Hope it helps.

Comment: The `(?<=...)` is unnecessary; `findall` already excludes the `{` from its output due to the capture group.

Comment: @chepner. You are right. And if so, it will do 16 steps !! Faster: _https://regex101.com/r/iZ9oG9/3_